# What does "root :0 " refers to in who command

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Myself root user checking the list of users whom were logged in my debian machine.

I checked it through `"who"` command ,The result was as :

```
root     :0           2015-09-30 09:30 (:0)
root     pts/0        2015-09-30 17:48 (:0)
```

I understand that its : user name, tty number, date and time ,But what does  `root :0` in the output refers to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's the default XWindows display. In the vast majority of cases, this is your machine's only graphical display. Did you log into the GUI as root?

Comment: yes spiff i was at gui